# How to move values from one dataframe to another in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df1 that looks like this:

```
           Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2009-01-14   AAPL   BUY     150
2009-01-21   AAPL  SELL     150
2009-01-21    IBM   BUY     400
```

And df2 looks like this:

```
           GOOG AAPL  XOM  IBM Cash
Date                               
2009-01-14  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-01-21  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I want to move the values in the first DF to the second so that the amount of shares populates under the appropriate stock symbol. So the above would look like:

```
           GOOG AAPL  XOM  IBM Cash
Date                               
2009-01-14  NaN  150  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-01-21  NaN  -150 NaN  400  NaN
```

How would I move all values that I have in my first dataframe to the second dataframe?

Comment: Are you just looking to pivot or actually fill data in another dataframe?:  `df.pivot(None, 'Symbol', 'Shares')`

Comment: What if a company has BUY and SELL on the same day?

Comment: @Chris actually fill it.

Comment: @coldspeed that's a good point, there shoudl actually be only a single line for that in the second df. I am going to edit now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need `df2` here. You can compute the result directly from `df` using some simple reshaping functions `set_index`, `unstack` and `reindex`. You just need the symbols list.

```
(df.assign(Shares=np.where(df.Order == 'BUY', df.Shares, -df.Shares))
   .drop('Order', 1)
   .set_index('Symbol', append=True)['Shares']
   .unstack(1)
   .reindex(df2.columns, axis=1))  # you can replace df2.columns with a list 

            GOOG   AAPL  XOM    IBM  Cash
Date                                     
2009-01-14   NaN  150.0  NaN    NaN   NaN
2009-01-21   NaN -150.0  NaN  400.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.select` to convert numbers to negative if `Order == 'SELL'` then `update`

```
df['Shares'] = np.select([df['Order'] == 'SELL'], [-df['Shares']], df['Shares'])
df2.update(df.pivot(None, 'Symbol', 'Shares'))


            GOOG   AAPL  XOM    IBM  Cash
Date                                     
2009-01-14   NaN  150.0  NaN    NaN   NaN
2009-01-21   NaN -150.0  NaN  400.0   NaN
```